# Laravel: Eloquent wherehas doesn't exclude records with certain value

Tags: laravel

I'm creating a SNS app, in which **User** and **Post** are in many-to-many relationship, with a pivot table **Favorite**. Is there way to fetch all posts you **didn't** faved?

```
$posts = Post::wherehas("users",function($q)use($your_id){
    $q->where('user_id', '!=', $your_id);
})->orDoesntHave('users')->get();

return $posts;
```

The above method was what I came up with, but it seemed not to work when more than 2 users faved the same post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to fetch all posts which not related with users favorites   thats mean dont have relationship with specific user , so you can use whereDoesntHave like this :-

```
$posts = Post::whereDoesntHave("users",function($q)use($your_id){
    $q->where('user_id', '!=', $your_id);
})->get();

return $posts;
```